# How to create Reset button in iPhone Settings

Tags: iphone, settings, reset

How can I create a **"button" in Settings** bundle? Something like "Import SIM Contacts" inside Mail settings? Or "Reset Calibration" in Nike + iPod application?

Need to have a "**Reset Username and Password**" button for Settings, if that is a special case... I mean how can I add logic to clear some of other settings, while my own app is not running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't run custom code in settings, so this is commonly solved with an on/off switch to reset settings at next launch.

When the app launches, check if it has been switched to on, and perform the reset in your application run-time.

Comment: Yep, seen switch in couple apps, too, and it was my backup plan. Too bad can't do a "Reset Button". Thanx for clearing up things!