# Reset iOS App Settings from Button in Settings

Tags: ios, settings, reset

I have some user-adjustable settings in `Settings.bundle/Root.plist`.

I want to enable the user to **reset these settings** to their default values with a button or similar **from outside the app**, right in the Settings.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959149/how-to-create-reset-button-in-iphone-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the default values and save them somewhere... when the user presses the "Revert to Default" button, you should go in and individually set all of the settings to the saved default values

Comment: An how can I place a button in the settings at all?

Comment: You could add a "Use Defaults" switch where on would be using the default values.

Comment: did it with the switch! i used `registerDefaults` and removed all of those when the switch was active. but i have to kill the app and start it again to reset the values.